# validating email input in angular - pattern validation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using template driven pattern to check if input is valid email and uses mat error to display it but it somehow does not work and I dont really understand why , as you can see in my code below I dont think there is still other way to do it , any idea why it does works guys ? Thanks.

whatever input it is always red even the email format is correct , why is that ?

[image]

#Email

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" fxFlex="30">
    <mat-label>EMAIL ADDRESS</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="email" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9._% -] @[a-zA-Z0-9.-] \.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$" [(ngModel)]="model.email"
        maxLength="100" #email="ngModel" required [readonly]="odel.assetStatus === 'Done'">
    <mat-error *ngIf="!model.email ">Inspector
        email is required.</mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="email.errors?.maxLength">Max
        length is 100.</mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="(email.errors && (email.invalid || email.touched))">InvalidEmail.</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the [EmailValidator](https://angular.io/api/forms/EmailValidator) from angular ?

```html
<input matInput type="email" email [(ngModel)]="model.email"
```

If you really want a custom regex, maybe [this](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/email-validation.php) will help

```js
/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/
```

Now what's wrong with your regex:

```js
^[a-zA-Z0-9._% -] @[a-zA-Z0-9.-] \.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
```

You made it so you can have only one letter, than a space, than `@`, than another letter, than a space, than a dot and 2 or 3 letters.
So only something like this will pass: `t @t .com`

The issue is with the spaces (after `@` and before `.`), you should put a `+` instead and everything would work:

```js
^[a-zA-Z0-9._% -]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
```

Comment: Hi Sir , first I am not using reactive form and will not use reactive form cause that would mean I have to update all of my code.

My issue is even with the correct regex it always displays the "Email is invalid " error , even if you repalce with correct email format it is still red

Comment: You don't need `ReactiveForms` for it to work. You have an example at the bottom of the documentation that uses `ngModel`

Comment: do you have stackblitz sample that it would work based on my example code above Sir ?

Comment: and with the example from the documentation how do we show errors ? like custom message

Comment: how do we show mat error message if we do that ?

Comment: the same way you show it right now, with `mat-error` in case you have errors.
I reproduced on stackblitz and it works for me, are you sure you don't have other errors in your error object? Because on the `*ngIf` you are checking for any errors on the field, not the email error
https://stackblitz.com/edit/kingsbury-angular-w-material-oy8u4d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: how does this example '232@gmailcom' became a valid email ? ,  as you can see that is wrong format Sir

Comment: you can put the pattern instead of email validator. That is how angular considers valid emails. I've changed the stackbltitz again please check

Comment: @DiyaAgastya, you should learn how to do basic forms before trying to do one. There's loads of videos on Youtube about it. You keep asking question for each input you're struggling on and this is not the right way to do. You can't just create a form without knowing what ngModel is, or using ReactiveForm.

Answer (score 1):

I got from this article https://www.abstractapi.com/guides/angular-email-validation , if you want to use the regex for validator email on the template-driven form you can try this pattern `^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$`

Comment: Still the same , the field still always displays red even I already input the correct email, once the valid email error shows it become permanent even I replace or erase it

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ATDPqMD

Comment: Do you have a sample project on stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z5kmt5-pazkg2?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html,app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts